# Simple Spring REST service doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, gradle, spring-boot

I am trying out Spring Boot to create a simple MongoDB REST service, but for the life of me cannot figure out why it is so resistant to start. I had these dependencies compiling at runtime with Gradle

```
compile('org.mongodb:bson:3.3.0')
compile 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.3.0'
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
compile('springframework:spring-web:1.2.6')
```

And the app was exiting early with some cryptic message:

```
Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext
```

So then I tried to add some *more* dependencies to see if that would help...god, I had dependencies:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
```

And that resulted in an even *more* cryptic message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAwareProcessor: method <init>()V not found
```

I feel like this process is unceccessarily complex to start such a simple service...I have done this with Express, Revel, and Django very simply, but Spring Boot just doesn't seem to make it easy. What am I missing about this process?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have incompatible Versions of sping jars in your classpath. The constructor ServletContextAwareProcessor() was intrduced in Version 4 of spring. PLease chck the Version of spring-context.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
compile('springframework:spring-web:1.2.6')
```

from your Gradle file. This artifact is ages old. The Spring Boot dependencies bring in all necessary Spring dependencies, so it is usually not necessary, to specify Spring dependencies itself.

Comment: Thanks! I'll need to remember to keep up-to-date dependencies next time

Comment: @pward Spring has a project generator which generates guaranteed valid Gradle or Maven projects with the correct dependencies, so you don't have to remember how to set it up: https://start.spring.io/